# Why can't I absolute-position generated content in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors

I'm creating a horizontal navigation bar.  Here's its CSS:

```
#topnav {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
}

#topnav ul {
    display: table-row;
}

#topnav ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #1b4260;
    position: relative;
}

#topnav a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 0px 15px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#topnav ul li+li:before{
    content: "*";
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    color: #ff0000;
    float: left;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<p>---</p>
<p>---</p>
<div id="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="blah">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="blah">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="blah">Item 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This creates a navigation bar with little asterisk separators.  It looks fine in every browser...

[image]

... except Firefox.  Firefox ignores "position: absolute" on the generated content:

[image]

Why would it do that?  Am I doing something wrong with my CSS?

Comment: I suspect this may be due to using display: table-x.  Have you tried making the :before display:table-cell instead of absolutely positioning it?

Comment: In order to control position a child element absolutely inside another element, the parent element needs to be relatively positioned first.

Comment: @Semicolon Hmm -- I hadn't tried that, no.  Looks like Jani Hyytiäinen found a solution, though.  Thanks!

Comment: @AngrySpartan Yup, looks like Jani concluded that as well.  Thanks for explaining why.

Comment: Adding points to a beneficial comment is always welcome =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to position the ul also:

```
#topnav ul {
    display: table-row;
    position:absolute;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/k5hVP/1/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not ideal, but I found a way to do it without positioning to top and without absolutely positioning the `ul`. You remove the top positioning, and use a margin-top to adjust the position of the asterisk.

http://jsfiddle.net/ajPLB/7/

Jani's solution concerns me because `position:relative` should theoretically work, as well (and it'd be the less intrusive solution), but it doesn't, which means the solution doesn't have anything to do with normal positioning priorities, and seems to rely on some odd way Firefox handles positioning priority.

Comment: Well, hmm, your concerns are valid, and your solution works for the test case, but I can't get it working in the site I'm working on, and I'm now running out of time to hammer out this problem. :-/  *sigh*  Thanks for the info, though.